# Google Sheets & Charts on HTML

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I couldn't really find the answer to this, but I'd like to know where to get started in making web applications like the title.

More specifically I have a script running on Google Sheets that is dynamically updating every so often (5 minutes?) of various information in the cells. I want to export that data to a table in a Google Chart and have that dynamically update on a HTML page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this has been [addressed by Google directly](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/spreadsheets).

Comment: I actually saw this and made the chart, but I couldn't figure out how to upload the chart to my html page...